# Seclected items from Toolbar search (jpGrid) are being unselected after Re-searching

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, toolbar

I have an issue with my `ToolBar` search in `jqGrid`. The problem occurs when I type a word in the search bar and select the desired items. Then, after I clear the search bar, I find that all the selected items are gone.

Anyone know what may be causing the problem?

Here is my code:

```
    $("#user_email_selector").jqGrid({
        datatype:"local",
        data:jqEmailArray,
        autowidth:false,
        width: '250',
        height:'150',
        rowNum:200,
        colNames:['user_id','user_name'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'user_id', index:'user_id', width:5, hidden:true},
            {name:'user_name', index:'user_name', width:20}
        ],
        sortname:'user_name',
        sortorder:"asc",
        multiselect:true,
    }); 

    $("#user_email_selector").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{autosearch:true,searchOnEnter:false});
```